# SQL Script does not publish

Tags: sql, visual-studio

When I publish my DB in in Visual Studio, my script does *not* publish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the script.
Select Properties.
Look at the Build Action.  Choose Build.

Try to publish again.

Also make sure you edit the DB csproj in and change from NONE to BUILD:

1. right click the DB project
2. unload project
3. right click the DB project
4. edit project
5. change the script property from NONE to BUILD.